# How to calculate probability of outcome of nonhomogenous Poisson process?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, integration, poisson-distribution

Suppose I have a nonhomogenous Poisson process with a known rate function $r(t)$ over a time window $[0,T]$. Now suppose I use this process to generate events and perfectly measure the arrival time of each event, i.e. a countable set of event occurrences $0 < t_1 < t_2 < \ldots < t_N < T$.

How would I calculate the probability of this outcome occurring?

Here's what I have so far:

The way I tried to go about this was to sample the domain into $K+1$ evenly spaced time points spaced at intervals of $dt=1/K$. Note that for any $t \in (0,T)$ the probability of an event occurring in the window $(t, t+dt]$ is $r(t)\, dt$.

Now, assume we estimate each $t_i$ as the closest point of the form $f(i)\,dt$, where $f: \{1,\ldots,N\} \to \{1,\ldots,K+1\}$. Also assume that $K$ is large enough so $f$ is injective. Then the probability of the continuous outcome can be estimated as the probability of a series of $K+1$ weighted coin flips:

$$P_K \left( \{t_i\}_{i=1}^N\right) = \prod_{j=0}^K q_K(j) \implies$$ $$\log \left( P_K \left( \{t_i\}_{i=1}^N \right) \right) = \sum_{j=0}^K q_K(j)$$ where $q_k(j)=r(j\,dt)\,dt$ if $\exists i$ s.t. $f(i)=j$ and $q_k(j)=1-r(j\,dt)\,dt$ if $\nexists i$ s.t. $f(i)=j$.

My issue is that I want to turn this sum into an integral as $K\to\infty$. However, since the set of event times is countable and therefore measure $0$, it seems that this would always converge to the integral $$\int_0^T 1-r(t)\, dt$$ regardless of when or how many of these events occurred. But clearly some outcomes of this experiment must be more likely than others.

How should I go about solving this problem?

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! But even if try to measure the likelihood of an outcome of a homogenous poisson process of constant rate, is there any way to express this in the language above? Wouldn't any discrete set of events in a real domain result in the same integral?

Answer (score 1):

The likelihood of observing the timestamps $0<t_1, \ldots, t_N<T$ under the inhomogeneous poisson process with rate function $r$ is

$$p(\{t_1,\ldots,t_N\}) = \left(\prod_{i=1}^N r(t_i)\right) \exp\bigg(-\int_{0}^T r(s)ds\bigg)$$

You can obtain it as follows:

For each $n, t$, denote $p(n,t)$ the probability that there are $n$ events in $[0,t]$.

We have the relationship

$$
\begin{aligned}
p(n,t+dt) 
&= p(n,t)p(\text{"no event in $[t,t+dt]$"}) + p(n-1,t) p (\text{"one event in $[t,t+dt]$"})\\
&= p(n,t)(1-r(t)dt) + p(n-1,t) r(t)dt\\
\end{aligned} 
$$

So

$$
\frac{p(n,t+dt)-p(n,t)}{dt} = r(t) \big[p(n-1,t) - p(n,t) \big]
$$

Indeed if the process is simple (no simultaneous events), then for small $dt$, $r(t)dt $ is the probability of an event happening in a small interval of size $dt$

For $n=0$ the term on the left is the probability of observing no event up to $t+dt$. Taking $dt\rightarrow 0$ we have $\frac{dp(0,t)}{dt} = -r(t)p(0,t)$

which solves as $$p(0,t) = \exp\left(-\int_{0}^t r(s)ds\right) .$$

For $n$ greater than 0, you can use induction and similar reasoning to find the probability that your events happened at the time they did and that nothing happend between them.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A_1,\ldots,A_k$ be an arbitrary decomposition of $[0,T]$ into disjoint Borel sets, i.e. $[0,T] = \sum_{i=1}^k A_i$ and $N_A$ be the number of occurences of the PP. Then $N_{A_1},\ldots,N_{A_k}$ are independent and $N_{A_i}$ is Poisson distributed $Po(\lambda_{A_i})$, where $\lambda_A = \int_A r(t)dt$.
Now put $A_1 = [t_1,t_1 + \Delta_1]$, $A_n = [t_n,t_n + \Delta_n]$ and $A_{n+1} = [0,T] \setminus \sum_{i=1}^n A_i$ (w.l.o.g. we assume that $A_1,\ldots,A_n$ are disjoint). Then $$\mathbb{P}(N_{A_1} = 1, \ldots, N_{A_n} = 1, N_{A_{n+1}} = 0) = \prod_{i=1}^n \lambda_{A_i} \cdot e^{-\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_{A_i}} \cdot e^{-\lambda_{A_{n+1}}}$$
and
$$\mathbb{P}(N_{A_1} = 1, \ldots, N_{A_n} = 1 | N_{A_{n+1}} = 0) = \prod_{i=1}^n \lambda_{A_i} \cdot e^{-\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_{A_i}}$$
(I don't know if the last expression is what you want.) If $r$ is sufficiently smooth and $\Delta_i \approx 0$ then
$$\prod_{i=1}^n \lambda_{A_i} e^{-\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_{A_i}} \approx \prod_{i=1}^n r(t_i) \Delta_i $$